# MySql count in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query that would return a table as followed:

1. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
2. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
3. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
4. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
5. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
6. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3
7. dayName, #ofStatus1,#ofStatus2,#ofStatus3

Basically I have a table where users get to enter cases. Each case has the following fields(datedCreated, status).

There are three (3) status possible (new, progress, closed)

So I would like to retrieve the number of each status for each day.

Each line would look something like this:

1. Monday, 8,3,2
2. Tuesday, 8,3,2
3. Wednesday, 8,3,2
4. ...

I have something that looks like this but can't seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT DAYNAME(dateAdded)AS Date, COUNT(status) AS Count, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(status, ',', "54") SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Text FROM clients GROUP BY DATE(dateAdded) ORDER BY dateAdded LIMIT 7
```

I know right now I have three colomns, but I need it to be in one columns.

Thank your for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT concat(
       DAYNAME(dateAdded),', '
       sum(case when status = 'new' then 1 else 0 end),','
       sum(case when status = 'progress' then 1 else 0 end),','
       sum(case when status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end)) as single_col
  FROM clients
 GROUP BY DATE(dateAdded)
 ORDER BY dateAdded
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the query was missing commas after each SUM (otherwise it wouldn't run) but even then, the result is unreadable. I get like: 4d6f6e6461792c302c312c31, 547565736461792c312c302c31, 5765646e65736461792c302c312c30 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just group concat the results?

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(t_date, t_new, t_progress, t_closed) AS 'Status Per Day'
FROM
(   SELECT 
        DAYNAME(dateAdded)AS t_date,
        SUM(status = 'new') t_new, 
        SUM(status = 'progress') t_progress,
        SUM(status = 'closed') t_closed 
    FROM clients 
    GROUP BY DATE(dateAdded) 
    ORDER BY dateAdded LIMIT 7
) t
GROUP BY t_date
```

Comment: It seems to return **[BLOB - 69 B]**

Comment: @onlymushu oops sorry forgot to add the group by.. try it now.